# Date TimeZone conversion in java?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I was looking for the simplest way to convert a date an time from GMT to my local time. Of course, having the proper DST dates considered and as standard as possible.

The most straight forward code I could come up with was:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String inpt = "2011-23-03 16:40:44";
Date inptdate = null;
try {
    inptdate = sdf.parse(inpt);
} catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
Calendar tgmt = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
tgmt.setTime(inptdate);

Calendar tmad = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
tmad.setTime(inptdate);

System.out.println("GMT:\t\t" + sdf.format(tgmt.getTime()));
System.out.println("Europe/Madrid:\t" + sdf.format(tmad.getTime()));
```

But I think I didn't get the right concept for what `getTime` will return.

Comment: How are you getting `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid")`
to work?Im getting the error 
`The method getTimeZone(String) is undefined for the type TimeZone`

Comment: Nothing fancy... This is a snippet the actual working code: http://pastebin.com/5u79mBMW Runs on Java 1.5 several times a day.

Comment: Ah apologies since writing this I have discovered that I am using the GWT version of TimeZone, and in that it doesn't allow a string as an argument!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

Comment: So your date is the 3rd day of the 23rd month of 2011?? Did you intend `2011-03-23 16:40:44`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The catch here is that the DateFormat class has a timezone. Try this example instead:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdfgmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    SimpleDateFormat sdfmad = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdfmad.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));

    String inpt = "2011-23-03 16:40:44";
    Date inptdate = null;
    try {
        inptdate = sdfgmt.parse(inpt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    System.out.println("GMT:\t\t" + sdfgmt.format(inptdate));
    System.out.println("Europe/Madrid:\t" + sdfmad.format(inptdate));
```

Comment: Didn't realise the DateFormat classes have their own timezone. Dates in Java are messy.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ;) but it kinda makes sense that DateFormat classes have a timezone, without knowing a timezone a string that represents some form of date isn't really meaningful (at least not without timezone information contained in the string) so in order to convert to a date from a simple datetime string you need to specify a timezone.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the 2017 answer.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String inpt = "2011-03-23 16:40:44";

    ZonedDateTime madridTime = LocalDateTime.parse(inpt, dtf)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"));

    System.out.println("GMT:\t\t" + inpt);
    System.out.println("Europe/Madrid:\t" + madridTime.format(dtf));
```

Please enjoy how much more naturally this code expresses the intent.

The code prints

```
GMT:        2011-03-23 16:40:44
Europe/Madrid:  2011-03-23 17:40:44
```

(with tab size of 8 it aligns nicely, but StackOverflow seems to apply a tab size of 4).

I swapped `23` and `03` in your input string, I believe you intended this. BTW, it wasn’t me catching your mistake, it was `LocalDateTime.parse()` throwing an exception because there is no 23rd month. Also in this respect the modern classes are more helpful than the outdated ones.

**Joda-Time?** [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24311668/5772882) mentions and recommends both `java.time`, which I am using, and Joda-Time. While Joda-Time is already a sizeable improvement over the outdated classes used in the question (`SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`), it is by now in maintenance mode; no greater further development is expected. `java.time` is hugely inspired by Joda-Time. For new code, I see no reason why you shouldn’t prefer `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

For the input, you can simply add the Timezone to the String (note the 'z' in the format):

```
new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").parse ("2011-23-03 16:40:44 GMT");
```

Comment: Also works with java7 (that's something incredible in 2021)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a decent date-time library rather than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. Instead use either Joda-Time or the java.time package found in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

```
String input = input.replace( " ", "T" ).concat( "Z" ) ; // proper ISO 8601 format for a date-time in UTC.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Madrid" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, timeZone );
String output = dateTime.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `TimeZone` on the `SimpleDateFormat`, using [`DateFormat.setTimeZone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29).