# Timezone conversion

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I need to convert from one timezone to another timezone in my project.

I am able to convert from my current timezone to another but not from a different timezone to another.

For example I am in India, and I am able to convert from India to US using `Date d=new Date();` and assigning it to a calendar object and setting the time zone.

However, I cannot do this from different timezone to another timezone. For example, I am in India, but I am having trouble converting timezones from the US to the UK.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/

Answer (score 60):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ))              // Current moment in a particular time zone.
             .withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ))  // Same moment adjusted into another time zone.
```

## Details

The java.util.Date class has no time zone assigned<sup>†</sup>, yet it's `toString` implementation confusingly applies the JVM's current default time zone.

## Avoid java.util.Date & .Calendar

This is one of many reasons to avoid the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date, .Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java. Avoid them. Instead use either:

- The [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and inspired by Joda-Time.
- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the [java.time package](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java) built-in. This package was inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). While they share some similarities and class names, they are different; each has features the other lacks. One notable difference is that java.time avoids constructors, instead uses static instantiation methods. Both frameworks are led by the same man, [Stephen Colbourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

In the case of this Question, they work in the same fashion. Specify a time zone, and call a [`now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) method to get current moment, then create a new instance based on the old immutable instance to adjust for time zone.

Note the two different time zone classes. One is a named time zone including all the rules for Daylight Saving Time and other such anomalies plus an offset from UTC while the other is only the offset.

```
ZoneId zoneMontréal = ZoneId.of("America/Montreal"); 
ZonedDateTime nowMontréal = ZonedDateTime.now ( zoneMontréal );

ZoneId zoneTokyo = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"); 
ZonedDateTime nowTokyo = nowMontréal.withZoneSameInstant( zoneTokyo );

ZonedDateTime nowUtc = nowMontréal.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

## Joda-Time

Some example code in Joda-Time 2.3 follows. Search StackOveflow for many more examples and much discussion.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneLondon = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" );
DateTimeZone timeZoneKolkata = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTimeZone timeZoneNewYork = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );

DateTime nowLondon = DateTime.now( timeZoneLondon ); // Assign a time zone rather than rely on implicit default time zone.
DateTime nowKolkata = nowLondon.withZone( timeZoneKolkata );
DateTime nowNewYork = nowLondon.withZone( timeZoneNewYork );
DateTime nowUtc = nowLondon.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );  // Built-in constant for UTC.
```

We have four representations of the same moment in the timeline of the Universe.

---

<sup>†</sup>Actually the `java.util.Date` class *does* have a time zone buried within [its source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java). But the class ignores that time zone for most practical purposes. So, as shorthand, it’s often said that j.u.Date has no time zone assigned. Confusing? Yes. Avoid the mess that is j.u.Date and go with Joda-Time and/or java.time.

Comment: Thanks, It was very useful your answer.

Comment: This post has the correct answer. On Oracle's java documentation they recomend the using Joda date prior Java 8 SE.



" Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310). "

Answer (score 39):

Some examples

[Convert time between timezone](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Converttimebetweentimezone.htm)

[Converting Times Between Time Zones](http://web.archive.org/web/20120413172225/http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/GetTimeOtherZone2.html)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZoneExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a calendar object and set it time based on the local
        // time zone
        Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        localTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
        localTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        localTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        int hour = localTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minute = localTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = localTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


        // Print the local time
        System.out.printf("Local time  : %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);


        // Create a calendar object for representing a Germany time zone. Then we
        // wet the time of the calendar with the value of the local time

        Calendar germanyTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        germanyTime.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
        hour = germanyTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minute = germanyTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        second = germanyTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


        // Print the local time in Germany time zone
        System.out.printf("Germany time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);
    }
}
```

Comment: exampledepot.com link no longer exists?

Comment: It seems that it is workable if you use `get(int)` to retrieve the fields and concat the date string by yourself. However, it does not work for `getTime()`, `getTime()` for localTime  and germanyTime are always the same, In short, you cannot easily produce another date object with hour, minute, second of another timezone. It is reasonable the dates are always the same with GMT time for different calendar, but I don't  understand why I can't easily change the internal states of a date object.  I see another solution for producing the date String is to use timezone setting on dateformat.

Answer (score 7):

```
    Date date = new Date();
    String formatPattern = ....;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatPattern);

    TimeZone T1;
    TimeZone T2;

    // set the Calendar of sdf to timezone T1
    sdf.setTimeZone(T1);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

    // set the Calendar of sdf to timezone T2
    sdf.setTimeZone(T2);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

    // Use the 'calOfT2' instance-methods to get specific info
    // about the time-of-day for date 'date' in timezone T2.
    Calendar calOfT2 = sdf.getCalendar();
```

Comment: This was the solution for me after several hours of googling. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The "default" time zone can be avoided entirely by just setting the time zone appropriately for the `Calendar` object. However, I would personally suggest that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a far superior API for date and time operations in Java. Amongst other things, time zone conversion is very simple in Joda.

It's not clear what your current code looks like and why you're only able to convert via the default time zone, but in Joda Time you'd just specify the time zone explicitly when creating (say) a [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object, and then use `withZone(DateTimeZone zone)`.

If you could tell us more about how you're getting input data, we could give a fuller example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code snippet

```
String dateString = "14 Jul 2014 00:11:04 CEST";
date = formatter.parse(dateString);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

// Set the formatter to use a different timezone - Indochina Time
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
System.out.println("ICT time : "+formatter.format(date));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use Joda, here is a deterministic way using the built in libraries.

First off I recommend that you force your JVM to default to a timezone.  This addresses the issues you might run into as you move your JVM from one machine to another that are set to different timezones but your source data is always a particular timezone.  For example, lets say your data is always PDT/PST time zone, but you run on a box that is set to UTC timezone.

The following code snippet sets the default timezone in my JVM:

```
 //You can either pass the JVM a parameter that 
 //enforces a TZ: java -Duser.timezone=UTC or you can do it
 //programatically like this
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
 TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
```

Now lets say your source date is coming in as PDT/PST but you need to convert it to UTC.  These are the steps:

```
    DateFormat dateFormatUtc = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatUtc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    String dateStrInPDT = "2016-05-19 10:00:00";
    Date dateInPDT = dateFormat.parse(dateStrInPDT);


    String dateInUtc = dateFormatUtc.format(dateInPDT);

    System.out.println("Date In UTC is " + dateInUtc);
```

The output would be:

```
Date In UTC is 2016-05-19 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### How to switch to the modern API?

Convert `java.util.Date` to `Instant` using [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
System.out.println(instant); // 2021-05-30T13:10:01.890Z
```

### What's `Instant` got to do with my requirement?

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in UTC. The `Z` in the sample output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours). Its zero-timezone offset makes it independent of timezones i.e. an instant is the same at every place in the world. It's analogous to water in the physical world.

You can mix a timezone (i.e. `ZoneId`) with an `Instant` by calling [`Instant.atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) to get the corresponding Date-Time in that timezone (i.e. `ZonedDateTime`).

Similarly, you can mix a timezone offset (i.e. `ZoneOffset`) with an `Instant` by calling [`Instant#atOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atOffset-java.time.ZoneOffset-) to get the corresponding Date-Time with that timezone offset (i.e. `OffsetDateTime`).

In the ***reverse way***, you can also get an `Instant` by calling `toInstant` on the `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        Instant instant = date.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);

        // The corresponding Date-Time in Chicago
        ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        System.out.println(zdtChicago);

        // The corresponding Date-Time in Kolkata
        ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(zdtKolkata);

        // The corresponding Date-Time at timezone offset of -05:00 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtAtOffsetMinus0500 = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
        System.out.println(odtAtOffsetMinus0500);

        // The corresponding Date-Time at timezone offset of +05:30 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtAtOffset0530 = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));
        System.out.println(odtAtOffset0530);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-30T13:44:26.599Z
2021-05-30T08:44:26.599-05:00[America/Chicago]
2021-05-30T19:14:26.599+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2021-05-30T08:44:26.599-05:00
2021-05-30T19:14:26.599+05:30
```

So far you have learnt a ***simple way*** to convert an `Instant` (which you have created directly or obtained from a `java.util.Date` or a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`) to a Date-Time in any timezone or at any timezone offset.

### Alternatively

There is ***another way*** to convert a `ZonedDateTime` from one timezone to another. Again, there is a similar method to convert an `OffsetDateTime` from one timezone offset to another.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Current Date-Time in Chicago
        ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
        System.out.println(zdtChicago);

        // The corresponding Date-Time in Kolkata
        ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdtChicago.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(zdtKolkata);

        // Current Date-Time at a timezone offset of -05:00 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtAtOffsetMinus0500 = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
        System.out.println(odtAtOffsetMinus0500);

        // The corresponding Date-Time at timezone offset of +05:30 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtAtOffset0530 = odtAtOffsetMinus0500.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));
        System.out.println(odtAtOffset0530);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-05-30T10:03:59.895923-05:00[America/Chicago]
2021-05-30T20:33:59.895923+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2021-05-30T10:03:59.897782-05:00
2021-05-30T20:33:59.897782+05:30
```

### When to use `ZonedDateTime` and when to use `OffsetDateTime`?

- If you are dealing with a fixed timezone offset value e.g. `02:00` hours, use `OffsetDateTime`. It is also supported by all JDBC drivers. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) to learn more about it.
- If you want the timezone offset to change automatically based on [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), use `ZonedDateTime`. Unfortunately, `ZonedDateTime` is not supported by JDBC.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `java.time.ZoneDateTime#ofInstant()` method:

```
import java.time.*;

public class TimeZonesConversion {
    static ZonedDateTime convert(ZonedDateTime time, ZoneId newTimeZone) {
        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
                time.toInstant(),
                newTimeZone);
    };

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ZonedDateTime mstTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.of("-07")); 
        ZonedDateTime localTime = convert(mstTime, Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone());
        System.out.println("MST(" + mstTime + ") = " + localTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you really mean by "converting".

It MAY be as simple as setting the time zone in the FORMATTER, and not mucking with Calendar at all.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

TimeZone tzUTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" );
TimeZone tzPST = TimeZone.getTimeZone( "PST8PDT" );

DateFormat dtfmt = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE, yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm a z" );

dtfmt.setTimeZone( tzUTC );
System.out.println( "UTC: " + dtfmt.format( cal.getTime() ));

dtfmt.setTimeZone( tzPST );
System.out.println( "PST: " + dtfmt.format( cal.getTime() ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to get the current time in another time zone.

```
Calendar japanCal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Japan"));
japanCal.setTimeInMillis(local.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer, but could help someone trying to generate dates with same timezone and apply another timezone's offset.
It is useful when your application server is running in one timezone and your database in another.

```
public static Date toGreekTimezone (Date date) {
  ZoneId greek = ZoneId.of(EUROPE_ATHENS);
  ZonedDateTime greekDate = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), greek);

  ZoneId def = ZoneId.systemDefault();
  ZonedDateTime defDate = greekDate.withZoneSameLocal(def);

  return Date.from(defDate.toInstant());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here a story:
my user in US enters a date in a web page. My server gets this as a `java.util.Date` object. `Date` objects have no notion of time zone.

so let's say user entered 11PM(== 4AM london time). For her this was 11PM US time.
Your server gets this and interprets this as 11PM of JVM's timezone.
but what you need is a `Date` object that represents 4AM.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String timeStringInUS =  sdf.format("2020-05-04 23:00:00");

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatInUS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatInUK = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

dateFormatInUS.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
dateFormatInUK.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));

Date dateInUS = dateFormatInUS.parse(timeStringInUS);
Date dateInUK = sdf.parse(dateFormatInUK.format(dateInUS));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convertTimeBasedOnTimeZoneAndTimePattern(String dateTime,
  String fromTimeZone, String toTimeZone, String originalTimePattern, String timePattern) {

  DateTimeFormatter formatterNew = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timePattern);

  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(originalTimePattern);

  TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(dateTime);
  ZoneId z = ZoneId.of(fromTimeZone);
  LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);
  ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, z);
  Instant instant = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);

  ZonedDateTime fromZonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of(toTimeZone));

  String fromZoneDateTime = fromZonedDateTime.format(formatterNew);

return fromZoneDateTime;}
```

To convert any time to the specific timezone (for example: UTC -> local timezone and vise versa) with any time pattern you can use java.time library.

This method will take time patterns (original and required format) and timezone (original time zone and required timezone) will give String as output. you can convert String to date by using SimpleDateFormatter or also use parse method of the ZoneDateTime/Instant class.

To convert String to date:

```
public static final DATE_FORMAT="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS";
public static Date convertStringToDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    Date parsedDate = null;

    try {
      parsedDate = formatter.parse(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new DateTimeParseException("Please provide date time in proper format", null, 0, null);
    }
    return parsedDate;
  }
```

To convert date to String:

```
public String convertTextDateToDate(Date textDate) {
    // SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", //Locale.ENGLISH);

    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    String dateFormatted = date.format(textDate);
    return dateFormatted;
  }
```

Comment: Your java.time code is more complicated than necessary, but thanks for showing the use of java.time.