# How to convert a data from 1 timezone to another timezone?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

I have a date in UTC, how to convert it to other timezone?

Comment: BTW: Java supports GMT, but not UTC as such.

Comment: It would help if you explain what you're doing with dates and time zones.

Answer (score 36):

### java.util.Date

Despite what the output of `Date.toString()` suggests, `Date` instances are **not** timezone aware. They simply represent a point in time, irrespective to the timezone. So if you have a `Date` instance, there is nothing more you need to do. And what if you have time in one time zone and you want to know what is the time in other time zone? You need

### java.util.Calendar

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"))
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15)  //15:00 in Tokyo
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER)

cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"))
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)  //17:00 in Melbourne
```

Note that after changing the time zone the date (point in time) didn't changed. Only the representation (current hour in this particular time zone). Also note that November is important there. If we change the month to July suddenly the hour in Melbourne changes to 16:00. That's because Tokyo does not observe DST, while Melbourne does.

### java.text.DateFormat

There is another catch in Java with time zones. When you are trying to format a date you need to specify time zone explicitly:

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getTimeInstance
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"))
```

Otherwise `DateFormat` always uses current computer's time zone which is often inappropriate:

```
format.format(cal.getTime())
```

Since `format()` method does not allow `Calendar` instances (even though it accepts `Object` as a parameter - sic!) you have to call `Calendar.getTime()` - which returns `Date`. And as being said previously - `Date` instances are not aware of time zones, hence the Tokyo and Melbourne settings are lost.

Comment: Thanks for the DateFormat tip!

Comment: Thank you, wish I found this ten years ago when you posted it.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Joda-Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). They have 2 functions called withZone() and withZoneRetainFields() to perform [timezone calculations](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Changing_TimeZone).