# How many ways to change a dateformat and timezone in java?

Tags: java

i know how to change date format in java, but i don't know how many ways to change date format in java please give me some brief detail.  And how to change the timezone in java.

Comment: Why do you want to know all of them? Use the ones you need.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:
[Simple Date Format - Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

And for the timezone -> [How to change TIMEZONE for a java.util.Calendar/Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470830/how-to-change-timezone-for-a-java-util-calendar-date)

But you should have found this via google search :(