# set timezone standard for java program

Tags: java, timezone

I have a junit test as stated below:

```
Calendar cal = somecode.getDate();
assertEquals("1941-02-31-05:00", cal.toString);
```

This passes in my local machine but in the sandbox due to timezone standard differences, the value of cal.toString() comes up as "1941-02-31Z". So, the assertion keeps failing. Does anyone know how I can make this pass in both the places without changing timezone standards or formats in either machines. May be just by setting a default time zone standard inside the code?

I cannot upgrade from Java 6. So, I need to find a solution inside the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470830/how-to-change-timezone-for-a-java-util-calendar-date

Comment: Since your test explicitly requires time zone `-05:00`, *it* should specify that by setting the time zone of the `Calendar` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`setTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) method to set the timezone to a particular value.

However, you also probably shouldn't be relying on the format of [`Calendar.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toString()):

> This method is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, and the format of the returned string may vary between implementations.

You should probably check the fields individually, rather than relying upon the string:

```
cal.setTimeZone(...);
assertEquals(1941, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
assertEquals(2, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
// ... etc.
```