# How to set offset of a java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have a Date as a String - `15Sep20162040`, which I have to format it into another format with Timezone as `2016-09-15T20:40:00+0400`.

What I did to do it as follows:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateFormatExample {

    private static SimpleDateFormat offsetDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "ddMMMyyyyHHmm");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = "15Sep20162040";
        String result = offsetDateFormat.format(dateFormatter.parse(date));
        System.out.println(result); // 2016-09-15T20:40:00+0400         

    }
}
```

Now, I have to modify the output based on timezone difference, for example if difference is `+0100`, output should resemble as: `2016-09-15T20:40:00+0100` and if difference is `-0200`, output should resemble as: `2016-09-15T20:40:00-0200`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: If possible, I recommend using the Java SE 8 Date and Time API. It is much simpler, clearer and thread safe (which `SimpleDateFormat` for example is not).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470830/how-to-change-timezone-for-a-java-util-calendar-date

Comment: That last part is confusing. Did you mean you want to adjust the same moment in various other time zones or offsets?

Comment: @BasilBourque  yes, same moment in different offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`'s `setTimeZone` method as below:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateFormatExample {

    private static SimpleDateFormat offsetDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "ddMMMyyyyHHmm");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date = "15Sep20162040";
        String result = offsetDateFormat.format(dateFormatter.parse(date));
        System.out.println(result); // 2016-09-15T20:40:00+0400
        offsetDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8:00"));
        result = offsetDateFormat.format(dateFormatter.parse(date));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

If you simply want to change the timezone at the end of `result`, please try the following:

```
    String offset = "GMT-8:00";
    String date = "15Sep20162040";
    date = date+" "+offset;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyyHHmm Z");
    SimpleDateFormat offsetDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    offsetDateFormat2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(offset));
    String result = offsetDateFormat2.format(dateFormatter2.parse(date));
    System.out.println(result);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Besides changing offset, it's changing time as well . It gives me output as - `2016-09-15T08:40:00-0800`, what I am expecting as - `2016-09-15T20:40:00-0800`

Comment: please check the updated answer..let me know if you need more changes

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    LocalDateTime.parse ( "15Sep20162040" , 
                          DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "ddMMMyyyyHHmm" )
                                           .withLocale( Locale.English ) 
                        )
                 .atZone ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Puerto_Rico" ) );
```

> 2016-09-15T20:40-04:00[America/Puerto_Rico]

```
zdt.atZone( ZoneId.of ( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Same moment viewed through different wall-clock time
```

> 2016-09-16T12:40+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

## Using java.time

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input string.

```
String input = "15Sep20162040";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "ddMMMyyyyHHmm" ).withLocale ( Locale.ENGLISH );
```

By the way, this is a terrible format for a date-time string. It assumes English, abuses English with incorrect abbreviation of month name, and is confusing and ambiguous. Instead, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when serializing date-time values to text.

## Un-zoned

Parse the input string as a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) since it lacks any info about [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

Understand that without an offset or time zone, this `LocalDateTime` object has no real meaning. It represents many possible moments, but not a specific point on the timeline. For example, noon in Auckland NZ is a different moment than noon in Kolkata India which is an earlier moment than noon in Paris France.

### Assign an offset-from-UTC

You indicate this date-time was intended to be a moment with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of four hours behind UTC (-04:00). So next we apply a `ZoneOffset` to get a `OffsetDateTime` object.

Tip: Always include the colon and the minutes and padding zeros in your offset-from-UTC strings. While not required by the ISO 8601 standard, common software libraries and protocols expect the fuller formatting.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( -4 ); 
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( offset );
```

### Assign a time zone

If by your context you knew of a time zone rather than a mere offset, use a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to instantiate a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Puerto_Rico" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

### Different time zones

Your question is not clear near the end, about changing offsets. If your goal is to view the date-time through the various lenses of various time zones, you can easily adjust by creating new `ZonedDateTime` objects. Assign a different time zone to each.

Note that all these date-time objects (zdt, zKolkata, and zAuckland) represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline. Each presents a different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) but for the **same simultaneous moment**.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant ( zKolkata );

ZoneId zAuckland = ZoneId.of ( "Pacific/Auckland" );
ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = zdt.withZoneSameInstant ( zAuckland );

System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | ldt: " + ldt + " | odt: " + odt + " | zdt: " + zdt + " | zdtKolkata " + zdtKolkata + " | zdtAuckland: " + zdtAuckland );
```

Dump to console.

> input: 15Sep20162040 | ldt: 2016-09-15T20:40 | odt: 2016-09-15T20:40-04:00 | zdt: 2016-09-15T20:40-04:00[America/Puerto_Rico] | zdtKolkata 2016-09-16T06:10+05:30[Asia/Kolkata] | zdtAuckland: 2016-09-16T12:40+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.