# Java output only show time in UNIX

Tags: java

How to display only time in UNIX? I only using java6. Can't upgrade the java cause have some inconvience cause.

```
 DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");     
 Calendar calConvert = Calendar.getInstance();
 String currDate = dateFormat.format(calConvert);
 int year = Integer.parseInt(currDate .substring(0, 4));
 int month = Integer.parseInt(currDate .substring(4, 6));
 int day = Integer.parseInt(currDate .substring(6));
 int hour = Integer.parseInt(candle2.sTransTimeTo.substring(0, 2));
 int minute = Integer.parseInt(candle2.sTransTimeTo.substring(2, 4));
 int second = Integer.parseInt(candle2.sTransTimeTo.substring(4));

 calConvert.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT + 8:00"));
 calConvert.set(year, month, day);
 calConvert.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
 calConvert.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
 calConvert.set(Calendar.SECOND, second); 
 candle2.sTransTimeTo = Long.toString(calConvert.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
```

candle2.sTransTimeTo is the time we need to display. 
**How to show only time?**

if i do as below coding:

```
calConvert.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT + 8:00"));    
calConvert.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
calConvert.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calConvert.set(Calendar.SECOND, second); 
candle2.sTransTimeTo = Long.toString(calConvert.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
```

Comment: What you are doing in that code seems way overcomplicated. Why not just do `int year = calConvert.get(Calendar.YEAR);` instead of first formatting it into a string and then parsing parts of the string again? Also, it's not clear what you are asking. What result exactly do you expect?

Comment: my expectation is i only wan show Time without date in UNIX.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). For Java 6 & 7 see the ThreeTen-Backport project.

Comment: @SharonWong (a) `org.threeten.bp.Instant.now().getEpochSecond()`  (b) Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the official Java documentation.
But for now the code below will give you a head start.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormattedDateTimeOnly {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DateFormat yourDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        Date date = new Date();
        String time = yourDateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
//instantiates a calendar using the current time in the specified timezone
Calendar cSchedStartCal=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
//change the timezone
cSchedStartCal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
```

From the question [How to change TIMEZONE for a java.util.Calendar/Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470830/how-to-change-timezone-for-a-java-util-calendar-date)

Answer (score 0):

To display the current local time you can simply do this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String text = dateFormat.format(new Date());

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: This i know...But i need in millisecond but only time without date

Comment: What do you mean, the number of milliseconds since midnight of the current day?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

To get count of whole seconds since the Unix epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

```
Instant.now()
       .getEpochSecond()
```

## Details

This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow, so briefly…

Use modern java.time classes, not the troublesome legacy `Date`/`Calendar` classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Use true time zones when known, rather the mere [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Assign a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Brunei" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To extract only the date, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, ask for a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

To extract only the time-of-day, convert to a `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

To generate strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString` on any java.time object. For other formats, see `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

➠ To get the number of seconds from the epoch reference date of `1970-01-01T00:00Z`, interrogate the `ZonedDateTime`. Some call this [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
long secondsFromEpoch = zdt.toEpochSecond() ;
```

To get the number of seconds from midnight, use `Duration`. Do not assume midnight is `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day might start at a time such as `01:00:00`. Ask java.time to determine the first moment of the day.

```
long secondsSinceStartOfDay = 
    Duration.between( 
        zdt.atStartOfDay( z ) ,  // Get first moment of the day, may or may not be `00:00:00`.
        zdt 
    ).getSeconds() ;             // Render duration as a total number of seconds.
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).