# SimpleDateFormat setTimeZone not working

Tags: java, datetime, groovy, timezone, simpledateformat

I am using the below code to cast time as `UTC` which is working

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import static java.util.Calendar.* 

def dt = "2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00"
def format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"

TimeZone tz  = TimeZone.getDefault(); //getting up local time zone
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);      
Date d = sdf.parse(dt);
TimeZone.setDefault(tz);

println d //output: 2018-03-19T05:00:00Z

println d.toTimestamp(); //Output: 2018-03-19 06:00:00.0
```

But when I use `TimeZone.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` then it not working.

It is working only with     `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Why so?

Update after comments: Outputs needs to be in CET but in UTC

```
def dt = "2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00"
def format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);      
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"))
Date d = sdf.parse(dt);

println d
println d.toTimestamp();
```

​
Output:

```
Mon Mar 19 05:00:00 UTC 2018
2018-03-19 05:00:00.0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "working" and "not working"? I strongly suspect you've misunderstood what a `Date` value actually contains. As your input data contains the UTC offset, the time zone in the SDF is irrelevant.

Comment: Your ```d``` is in no way tied to your ```tz```

Comment: See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/ for details about java.util.Date, btw. I'd also suggest using java.time if at all possible.

Comment: @j.seashell: You can't set a time zone on a `Date`. It's a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Comment: @JonSkeet apologies, edit made

Comment: Please check outputs in prinln, timestamp shouldn't be in UTC as well?

Comment: @JonSkeet Input `2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00` is in CET format date right?? not UTC

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470830/how-to-change-timezone-for-a-java-util-calendar-date

Comment: Firstly, a "format" isn't the same as a time zone. All we know about the value is that it has an offset of UTC+1. But note that 2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00 and 2018-03-19 05:00:00.0 (UTC) are the same value. It's really unclear at this point what you want - half the time you say you want UTC, and the other half of the time you say you want CET. But a `Date` is neither - it's just an instant in time. If you want a value converted with a given format and with respect to a given time zone, use `SimpleDateFormat.format`... or better, use `java.time` and format with that instead.

Comment: you save me) I had been trying to repair not working         TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone); several hours. Omg! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### java.time

```
    String dt = "2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dt);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This prints

> 2018-03-19T06:00+01:00

Contrary to the outdated `Date` class, an `OffsetDateTime` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, does contain a UTC offset, as the name also says. I don’t have experience with Groovy, so sorry to have to trust you to translate from my Java code.

If you want to make sure you get a specific time zone regardless of which offset is in the string:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels");
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dt).atZoneSameInstant(zone);
```

This time the result is:

> 2018-03-19T06:00+01:00[Europe/Brussels]

Don’t rely on three letter time zone abbreviations like CET. CET is a common name for the standard time half (the part without summer time/DST) of very many European time zones that generally share time, but have not always done so and tend to disagree on the time when it comes to historic dates. Other three letter abbreviations are ambiguous and thus lead to even more confusion. Always give time zone as region/city, as I did with Europe/Brussels. Of course, pick the city that matches your desired time zone.

If you think you need a `java.sql.Timestamp` — you may not need that. If using JDBC 4.2 or higher or a similarly modern JPA implementation, it is better to store either an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime` to your database. The choice depends on your exact requirements and the exact datatype of your database column.

```
    Instant inst = dateTime.toInstant();
    System.out.println(inst);
```

Output

> 2018-03-19T05:00:00Z

`Instant`s always print in UTC. If a sufficiently new JDBC driver is unavailable, you may convert to `Timestamp` in either of two ways:

```
    System.out.println(Timestamp.from(inst));
    System.out.println(Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime.toLocalDateTime()));
```

> 2018-03-19 06:00:00.0
>  2018-03-19 06:00:00.0

Because my time zone agrees with the time zone in the date-time object, I get the same result from both conversions. In other time zones the result may not be the same, and you will need to take care to pick the correct one.

### What went wrong in your code?

When you use `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing a string with a UTC offset in it, it uses that offset for determining the point in time. In this case it does not use the time zone you have set through `setTimeZone` for anything. And it doesn’t put any time zone or offset into the `Date` it returns because a `Date` cannot contain a time zone. It is just a point in time.

What confuses many is that the result of `Date.toString()` seems to contain a time zone abbreviation, as UTC in your output `Mon Mar 19 05:00:00 UTC 2018`. What happens is that `toString()` uses the JVM’s time zone setting for generating the string. This is why `TimeZone.setDefault()` affects the output you get: it sets the JVM setting, affecting all programs running in the same JVM. It doesn’t affect the `Date` object itself, however, only the result of its `toString()`.

The `TimeZone`, `Date` and `Timestamp` classes are long outdated. `SimpleDateFormat` is too and at the same time notoriously troublesome. I recommend you don’t use those classes at all. `java.time` is so much nicer to work with.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.