# Java- Set time zone with values as UTC-1 to UTC-12 and UTC+1 to UTC+12

Tags: java

I'm converting timezone with values as UTC-1,...,UTC-12, however while printing it date/time it's not displaying converted time zone.

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-1"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(actualDate)); // actualDate showing older time zone and not according to UTC-1
```

Instead of using UTC-1,UTC-2...and so on, if i use "America/New_York", it shows correct timezone.

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(actualDate)); // actualDate showing updated time zone EDT
```

Please suggest if i'm missing something, as I wanted to use values as UTC-1, UTC-2,...UTC+1 and so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451976/simpledateformat-settimezone-not-working

Comment: Thank for pointing to post. However even if i use Calendar, it's behaving same.   final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-1"));
  calendar.setTime(actualDate);

Comment: Show example inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TL;DR:** To support `"UTC"` prefix, use `ZoneId`. See end of answer.*

---

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(String ID)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-), it says:

> Gets the `TimeZone` for the given ID.
>
> **Parameters:**
> ID - the ID for a TimeZone, either an abbreviation such as "PST", a full name such as "America/Los_Angeles", or a custom ID such as "GMT-8:00". Note that the support of abbreviations is for JDK 1.1.x compatibility only and full names should be used.
>
> **Returns:**
> the specified TimeZone, or ***the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood.***

So lets test that:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-1"));
```

*Output*

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

The javadoc did say that `GMT-8:00` is valid, so lets test that:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));
```

*Output*

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT-01:00",offset=-3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

If you **read the javadoc** of [`TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) itself:

> If the time zone you want is not represented by one of the supported IDs, then a custom time zone ID can be specified to produce a TimeZone. The syntax of a custom time zone ID is:
>
> ```
>  CustomID:
>          GMT Sign Hours : Minutes
>          GMT Sign Hours Minutes
>          GMT Sign Hours
>  Sign: one of
>          + -
>  Hours:
>          Digit
>          Digit Digit
>  Minutes:
>          Digit Digit
>  Digit: one of
>          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```

As you can see, custom time zones **must** start with `GMT`.

---

The new Java 8 Time API supports `UTC-1`, e.g.

```
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("UTC-1"));
```

*Output*

```
UTC-01:00
```

Which means that if your `actualDate` value is a `java.util.Date`, then you can format it like this:

```
Date actualDate = new Date();
System.out.println(actualDate);

DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z")
                                                .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC-1"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(actualDate.toInstant()));
```

*Output*

```
Mon Dec 30 02:29:41 EST 2019
2019-12-30 06:29:41 UTC-01:00
```

As you can see, the time was adjusted to the `UTC-01:00` time zone.

Comment: Thanks, your last end of answer helps, it solves my problem.