# Java util calendar - is it enough to set timezone to get time in another timezone

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I need to get hours value of Calendar time in another timezone. I tried this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695910/775523 (java.util.Calendar section) but it prints 15 for the last cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) (I expect to have 17!).
So what is a correct way to get number of hours in another timezone - I use build 1.7.0_21-b11.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change TIMEZONE for a java.util.Calendar/Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470830/how-to-change-timezone-for-a-java-util-calendar-date)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code reference

```
    Date date = new Date();  
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");          
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));  
    // Prints the date in the CET timezone  
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));  
    // Set the formatter to use a different timezone  
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"));  
    // Prints the date in the IST timezone  
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

you can use date.getHours();