# TimeZone in Java Calendar

Tags: java

I want to perform operations using the `calendar.getinstance()` Method. But I am confused that whether it is timezone independent or timezone dependent.

If it is timezone dependent please suggest me to how to make it timezone independent.

Comment: might be a duplicate, have a read through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695859/how-to-convert-a-data-from-1-timezone-to-another-timezone

Comment: A `Calendar` always has a timezone.  What exactly do you mean by "timezone independent"?

Comment: @DavidWallace I want to use GMT timezone.

Comment: OK, then this question is either a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21349475 or of http://stackoverflow.com/q/308683 and I would suggest reading both of them.

Answer (score 2):

You have four possiblities.
From the JavaDoc:

- `Calender.getInstance()` will return a Calender-object using the
  default time zone and locale.
- `Calender.getInstance(TimeZone zone)`
  will return a Calendar-object using the specified time zone and
  default locale.
- `Calender.getInstance(Locale aLocale)` will return a
  Calendar-object using the default time zone and specified locale.
- `Calender.getInstance(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale)` will return a
  Calendar-object using the specified time zone and locale.

And as the following quote from the Calendar JavaDoc states, the Calender-object is always TimeZone dependant. The purpose of the object is the transformation between the milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian) into YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR and so on. The later information is always TimeZone dependant.

> The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for
>   converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar
>   fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, and so on, and for
>   manipulating the calendar fields, such as getting the date of the next
>   week. An instant in time can be represented by a millisecond value
>   that is an offset from the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT
>   (Gregorian).

Comment: For Calender.getInstance() what will be default time zone and locale?

Comment: That depends on your operating system.