# Convert timezones in ColdFusion with Java but can't get new time

Tags: java, coldfusion, timezone, lucee

I have a simple script

```
<cfscript>
public string function convertTimeZone( 
    string  toTimeZone  = "America/New_York"
,   date    thisDate  = now()
){
    var azTimeZone = createObject("java", "java.util.TimeZone").getTimeZone(javaCast("string","US/Arizona"));
    var azCalendar = createObject("java", "java.util.GregorianCalendar" ).init(azTimeZone);

    azCalendar.set(
        javaCast( "int", year( arguments.thisDate ) ),
        javaCast( "int", (month( arguments.thisDate ) - 1) ),
        javaCast( "int", day( arguments.thisDate ) ),
        javaCast( "int", hour( arguments.thisDate ) ),
        javaCast( "int", minute( arguments.thisDate ) ),
        javaCast( "int", second( arguments.thisDate ) )
    );
    var newCal = azCalendar.clone();
    newCal.setTimeInMillis(azCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    newCal.setTimeZone(javaCast("string",arguments.toTimeZone));


    writeOutput('AZ Cal');
    writeDump(azCalendar);
    writeDump(azCalendar.Timezone);
    writeDump(azCalendar.Time);
    writeDump(azCalendar.getTime());
    writeOutput('New Cal');
    writeDump(newCal);
    writeDump(newCal.Timezone);
    writeDump(newCal.Time);
    writeDump(newCal.getTime());

}

convertTimeZone();
</cfscript>
```

If you look at the output you will see that the new calendar contains the correct timezone and time but if I use getTime() it is not returning the correct value.  I am sure that I have done something either in setting the time in the new calendar or maybe even the clone but I can't quite figure it out.

If I add `writeDump(newCal.getTimezone());` to the list of dumps I do get "America/New_York"

[image]

Comment: I think you're experiencing what's explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13472173/985709) and the [link shared in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695910/985709).

Comment: Have you checked out the timezone.cfc library? https://github.com/rip747/TimeZone-CFC  It has a lot of functions that will enable you to identify DST & offset based on 92 different US/CA timezones.

Answer (score 1):

You can "trick" ColdFusion into using timezone adjusted date objects (since `java.util.Date` cannot be timezone aware).

```
<cfscript>

    srcDate = createDateTime(2017, 10, 07, 16, 33, 37);
    srcTZ   = "US/Arizona";

    dstTZ   = "America/New_York";

    TimeZone = createObject("java", "java.util.TimeZone");
    srcTZinfo = TimeZone.getTimeZone(srcTZ);
    dstTZinfo = TimeZone.getTimeZone(dstTZ);

    srcOffset = (srcTZinfo.getRawOffset() / 1000);
    dstOffset = (dstTZinfo.getRawOffset() / 1000);

    srcDSToffset = (srcTZinfo.getDSTSavings() / 1000);
    dstDSToffset = (dstTZinfo.getDSTSavings() / 1000);

    src2utc = dateAdd("s", -(srcOffset + srcDSToffset), srcDate);
    utc2dst = dateAdd("s",  (dstOffset + dstDSToffset), src2utc);

</cfscript>

<cfdump label="#srcTZ#" var="#srcDate#">
<cfdump label="#dstTZ#" var="#utc2dst#">
```

The snippet converts the source date object `srcDate` into a UTC date using the specified timezone `srcTZ`. The UTC date is then adjusted to the desired timezone `dstTZ` and the final date object put into `utc2dst`.

Comment: Thanks Alex,  I was trying to avoid the whole offset calc.  I am now more interested on why I can get the correct time INTO the `newCal` object but can't seem to get it out of the object

Comment: Because the time is returned as offset to UTC i.e. not aware of a timezone. That's simply a problem with Java's old date/time classes, which was tackled in Java 8 (`java.Time`). You have to add the offset of the desired timezone. You can use ColdFusion's [`dateConvert("local2Utc", now())`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateConvert.html) to get the UTC right away.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it *doesn't* contain the correct time. The presentation in the dump just makes it seem that way. `WriteDump()` must apply extra magic when displaying Calendar objects.

The date value does not change due to how `newCal` is created. Instead of cloning `azCalendar`, create a new instance and apply the `azCalendar` time with `set(...)`. Then the date value will change. However I'm not sure it works as expected for arbitrary time zones, only the jvm default

Supposedly Java 8+ has improved date options, which are worth investigating. For earlier versions I have used the [SimpleDateFormat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262055). Create two formatters. One to parse the input using the original time zone. Another to format the output, using the desired time zone. Then convert the final string back into a date object with parseDateTime().

```
thisDate = now();
fromTimeZone = "America/Phoenix";
toTimeZone = "America/New_York";

dateMask = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
timeZone = createObject("java", "java.util.TimeZone");

fromFormat = createObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init(dateMask);
fromFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone.getTimeZone(fromTimeZone));
// parse input as date string
dateString = dateTimeFormat(thisDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:nn:ss");
fromDate = fromFormat.parse(dateString); 

// format output as date string
toFormat = createObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init(dateMask);
toFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone.getTimeZone(toTimeZone));

// convert back into date
toDate = parseDateTime(toFormat.format(fromDate));
writeDump(toDate);
```