# Java Timezone Conversion : Help Required

Tags: java, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

I have to convert given time and timezone with some other timezone using Java code.

For Example :

I have to convert `28 Sept 2:00 PM IST` in Canada timezone with considering DST (Day Light Saving Time) as well.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/util/DateTimeUtils.java)

Answer (score 1):

Try `getTimeZone()` and `setTimeZone()` along with `Calendar` class

```
TimeZone oztz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Atlantic");
Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance( oztz );
```

**See this link for all Time-Zones :**

http://snipplr.com/view/23131/timezone-enum/

Answer (score 0):

The [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class has built in methods for doing the conversion.

You can set the desired timezone with [setTimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29).

Also see the [getTimeZoneOffset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTimezoneOffset%28%29) from the Date class.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like this :
[Converting Times Between Time Zones](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/GetTimeOtherZone2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#TimeZones) and its support for different timezones.

Namely, if you know you have string ISO format or a specific known format (like it looks like), you could do something like:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone("Asia/Kolkata");
DateTime newDate = fmt.parseDateTime([your input date]);
// You can manipulate your date here...
String newString = fmt.withZone("Canada/Atlantic").print();
```

This handles internally all Timezone matters, included DST.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is set Datetime and Timezone to Calender and getTime. Below is sample code which will set Timezone and user specific time.

```
Date date =new Date(2012,9,28,2,00,00); //Set time to Date
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Atlantic"));
        calendar.setTime(date);

        System.out.println("Timezone :: " + calendar.getTimeZone());
        System.out.println("Time :: " + calendar.getTime());
```

Output:

```
 Timezone :: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Canada/Atlantic",offset=-14400000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=228,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Canada/Atlantic,offset=-14400000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=3,startDay=1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
    Time :: Mon Oct 28 02:00:00 GMT 3912
```

You will get all information from TimeZone useDaylight(true/false), dstSaving(1 hour for canada)
For more functionality of TimeZone please refer below link:
http://biese.wordpress.com/2006/10/23/java-daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone/

Here is link to get DayLightSavingTime information:
http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=1187&year=2012