# How to convert date formats from one timezone to another with day light in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, dst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

I want to write a java code for converting date formats from one timezone to another with daylight.
I am using Oracle Database.
Any Thoughts?

Comment: you mean like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion

Answer (score 0):

You would like to do this

```
Date date = new Date();  

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");  
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));  

// Prints the date in the CET timezone  
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));  

// Set the formatter to use a different timezone  
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));  

// Prints the date in the IST timezone  
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```