# Convert UTC time to local time java Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, utc

Im retrieving some values from a json service and the retrieved datetime values are stored in UTC format.
i've tried a lot of sample codes to convert the datetime values to user local timezone but im still getting the same value after conversion.

This is what i have actually: (copied from other posts)

```
String sJsonDate = "2015-07-08T12:08:13.0625+00:00";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
try {
    Date localDateTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(sJsonDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result value (localDateTime) is the same as the original value.
I am in Paraguay (GMT-4) and the resulting values needs to be minus one hour diference, like this: ("2015-07-08 07:13:25") (The values are stored in Argentina)

Help please!

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion

Comment: which of the answers?

Comment: One that says to use Joda time

Comment: can you reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution, we are using day light savings so i had to disccount one hour to the resulting datetime.

So, i share the code for someone else:

```
public Date getDateInTimeZone(Date currentDate, String timeZoneId) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneId);

    Date localDateTime = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + timeZone.getOffset(currentDate.getTime()));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(localDateTime.getTime());
    if (timeZone.useDaylightTime()) {
        // time zone uses Daylight Saving
        cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeZone.getDSTSavings() * -1);// in milliseconds
    }

    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Usage:

```
String sDate = "2015-07-08T12:08:13.0625+00:00";
try {    
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            Date theDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(sDate);
            Date localDateTime = getDateInTimeZone(theDate, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```