# Java Instant to Date - With Different Timezone

Tags: java, date

I am running my code in EST timezone.

Using `Instant.now()` in my code and it returns time in UTC.

But, I am trying to test a method which gets data from DB as Date not Instant and hence trying to convert this to Date using

```
Date.from(Instant.now())
```

Since, I am running this in EST, this `Date` gives me time in EST.

Actual code,

```
    final Optional<Date> dbTime = dbService.getUpdatedTime();
    final Instant lastInstant = dbTime.orElseGet(() -> Date.from(Instant.now())).toInstant();
```

Test Code,

```
final Date dbTime = Date.from(Instant.now().minusSeconds(36000));
when(dbService.getUpdatedTime().thenReturn(Optional.of(dbTime));
```

Here, the `dbTime` gets converted to EST time. I can make that to return UTC time by setting `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Is there any other better way? Is this ok to set `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` in the main Application class so that it will always be treated as UTC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

Comment: A `Date` doesn't have a time zone. It's just an instant in time. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: @JonSkeet is right. So you basically don’t have a problem. It’s just `Date.toString()` that led you to believe you had one.

Comment: To clarify: The legacy class `java.util.Date` and the modern `java.time.Instant` both represent a moment in UTC. `Instant` replaced `Date`. No need to mix the classes. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, never use `Date`, always use `Instant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First recommendation, since you can use the modern Java date and time API, use it as much as you can and minimize the use of the outdated `Date` class. Best will be if you can modify `getUpdatedTime()` to return an `Optional<Instant>` rather than an `Optional<Date>` (a modern JDBC driver can give you the datetime from your database as an `Instant` directly). Since an `Instant` prints in UTC, this should wipe away all of your issue and your question.

In this answer I am assuming that you either cannot do that or don’t want to do it just yet. You can still get close, though:

```
    final Optional<Instant> dbTime = dbService.getUpdatedTime().map(Date::toInstant);
    final Instant lastReconInstant = dbTime.orElseGet(Instant::now);
```

Avoid `TimeZone.setDefault()`. Since the JVM only has one global time zone setting, this may unintentionally change the behaviour of other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM.

A detail, in your stub code I recommend to make it explicit that you subtract 10 hours. Two options are

```
    final Date dbTime = Date.from(Instant.now().minus(10, ChronoUnit.HOURS));

    final Date dbTime = Date.from(Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofHours(10)));
```

All of this said, it still seems to me that you didn’t have a problem in the first place. A `Date` does not have a time zone in it. Its `toString` method just grabs the JVM’s default time zone and uses it for rendering the date and time. This has fooled many and is just one of the reasons to avoid that class when you can.