# How to get timezone from given datetime string in java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, timezone

I want to take timezone from provided date and time as a string and want to convert it into local timezone datetime. 
My Simple date format is

> *"EEE yyyy-MM-dd 'at' hh:mm:ss aa zzz"*

Accroding to this the date from client is coming as

> Thu 2018-08-02 at 07:10:19 am PST

Now I want to take PST as timezone and convert date and time in local timezone (for eg. IST)

I am using JAVA 8.

Comment: You should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

Comment: @user12346352 Not exactly a duplicate. That Question is more general, where this Question starts with a `java.util.Date` object in hand (apparently, not sure as Question is poorly composed).

Comment: You basically cannot. PST is ambiguous, it could be Phillipines Standard Time, Pitcairn Standard Time or Pacific Standard Time (don’t know if there are more possibilities).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myJavaUtilDate                     // Some `java.util.Date` object. This troublesome class is obsolete.
.toInstant()                       // Convert from terrible legacy class to modern *java.time* class. Both represent a moment in UTC, always UTC.
.atZone(                           // Adjust from `Instant` in UTC to a `ZonedDateTime` in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )    // Specify time zone with `Continent/Region` name, never 3-4 letter pseudo-zone.
)                                  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                        // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append name of zone.
```

## java.time

So you have a `java.util.Date` object in hand? Convert from that terrible old outmoded class to its modern replacement, `java.time.Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To generate a string is standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets, call `toString`.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;  // Standard ISO 8601 format, extended by appending name of zone.
```

For other formats, [search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20%2Bjava%20%2BDateTimeFormatter&t=osx&ia=web). This has been discussed many many times already.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can Format your date like this:

```
Date date = new Date();

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Please do not suggest to a Java 8 user to use the `Date` or the `Calendar` classes. They are very outdated, and shouldn't be used in modern code.

Comment: The date was only a example but the `SimpleDateFormat` should not be outdated as far as I know

Comment: It is, because it works only with `Date`. Nowadays one should work with classes from the `java.time` and `java.time.format` packages.

Comment: I have also used `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` in Java 9 and i have never gotten any Problem with it... Which Problem can apear if I still use this functions instead of the `Java.time.format` package

Comment: I have wriiten code 
 'DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy-MM-dd 'at' hh:mm:ss aa zzz");
    Date date = formatter.parse("Thu 2018-08-06 at 08:10:19 pm IST");
    System.out.println(date);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));'

And output is when my default timezone is EDT:
 Mon Aug 06 14:10:19 EDT 2018
Mon 2018-08-06 at 02:10:19 PM EDT

which is not correct I guess. Can you tell me why? Am I missing something or doing wrong

Comment: @Pratty What I see the second part of your date is correct, why does he print the first part too where does he get the first one? From your Code I can't understand that but I think `Mon 2018-08-06 at 02:10:19 PM EDT` is correct right

Comment: @user12346352 if we convert 08:10:19 IST to EDT it should be in between 10 to 11 AM not 2:00 right?

Comment: Whether a given class is outdated or not isn’t a hard fact. Those who know certainly have considered `SimpleDateFormat` outdated for a long time now. I agree that suggesting it is poor advice.