# How to convert IST timezone to MST timezone

Tags: java, sql-server

In my web page user created the account with setting the time zone as MST. when user login from IST time zone it displaying IST time but it has to display MST timezone. So, I want to convert IST timezone to MST timezone.

Comment: Did you try googling this? It's a good idea to update the question with what have you tried and what doesn't seem to be working for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

Comment: Considering that your data is Timezone dependant, I *assume* you therefore are using `datetimeoffset`, as you aren't storing your values as UTC?