# Java How to convert specific time to different time zone

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a time for example `25 May 2021 02:00:00 PM EDT` (it is not the local time now), and I need to convert that time to time in different time zone (for ex: Paris time) which should be `25 May 2021 08:00:00 PM CET`
How can I do this using java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

Comment: 0. Don't use `Date`, `Calendar` or `SimpleDateFormat`. 1. Parse to a `ZonedDateTime`. 2. Specify the new timezone with something like `atZone`.

Comment: Why not just consult time API from the internet rather than trying reinventing the wheel?

Comment: the issue is when I use ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = sentTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")); It just simply gives me this: 2021-05-27T15:17:50.805+02:00[Europe/Paris] , which is my current time and not converted to the "Europe/Paris"

Comment: @reborn I would be happy to, but that's what I'm asking how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `EDT` and `CET` as these are not real time zones. Real time zones have a name in format of `Continent/Region`. For example, `America/New_York`  and `Europe/Paris`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    ZonedDateTime.of (
        2021 , 
        5 , 
        25 ,
        2 ,
        0 ,
        0 , 
        0 ,
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
    )
;
```

Adjust to another zone.

```
ZoneId zoneTunis = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdtTunis = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zoneTunis ) ;
```

Search to learn more. These topics have been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: this looks like what I was looking for, I was missing using withZoneSameInstant and that's why it didn't work. Also any suggestions how to convert EDT to "America/New_York"? because that's what I have as an input

Comment: @harmatii1 You will find many existing Questions on Stack Overflow about parsing such strings. The *java.time* classes can make a *guess* about those pseudo-zones but cannot perfectly map them to real time zones as some are not unique: CST, IST, etc. And educate the publisher of your data about proper data-exchange of date-time values: (a) using UTC (offset of zero) and (b) using only ISO 8601 formats.