# JAVA: gmt to local time conversion

Tags: java, timezone

I am developing a software in java.

I get a timestamp in GMT from a server.
The software can be used anywhere in the world. 
Now I want to get the local time zone where the software is running and convert this GMT time to the local time.

Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: wont a simple  Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName() give u the local time zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your local timezone :

Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName()

For the conversion:

[Date TimeZone conversion in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422089/date-timezone-conversion-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `timestamp` is either a `Date` or `Number`:

```
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(timestamp));
```

If your timestamp is given as a `String`, you first have to parse it. You'll find plenty of examples with custom format in [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), a simple example with built-in format:

```
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
final Date timezone = formatter.parse("2012-04-14 14:23:34");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(timezone));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Joda-Time. It has all the date related functions one needs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the server time in format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` this works:

```
String serverTime = "2017/12/06 21:04:07.406"; // GMT
ZonedDateTime gmtTime = LocalDateTime.parse(serverTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
LocalDateTime localTime = gmtTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
```