# Convert a given time to local time

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to convert 2015-01-04T19:50:26+08:00 to local time("Australia/Melbourne") in Java.May I know what are the libraries I can use for this??

Comment: Take a look at these, it may help: [Date TimeZone conversion in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422089/date-timezone-conversion-in-java) [Java Convert GMT/UTC to Local time doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375357/java-convert-gmt-utc-to-local-time-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: HI @Sarah, Yes that helps. But can you explain me this bit? 2015-01-04T19:50:26+08:00 is GMT time. Isn't it?

Comment: The Answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422089/date-timezone-conversion-in-java

Comment: @navrani and HAYMbl4, I discourage using the answers found in the question both of you are linking to. Most of them use the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class, while the least poor of them uses Joda-Time, which is also being discontinued.

Comment: The modern Java date & time API, AKA as `java.time` or JSR-310, is very well suited for tasks like yours. [Tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Excuse my frankness, what did you try before posting your question? I am sure your search engine could help you faster and better than anyone can post an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply adding or subtracting hours following this table:

|Western Standard Time|>. add 8 hours to UTC|

|Western Summer Time|>. add 9 hours to UTC|

|Central Standard Time|>. add 9:30 hours to UTC|

|Central Summer Time|>. add 10:30 hours to UTC|

|Eastern Time|>. add 10 hours to UTC|

|Eastern Summer Time|>. add 11 hours to UTC|

Table from [earthsky](http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/universal-time).

I would do it declaring a dictionary with name of location as `key` and hours as `value`. **Negative values mean substract.**

Hope it helps you.

Comment: While that would work, it doesn’t take into account that offsets have historically changed and may change again in the future. Since Java installations come with time zone information, it’s generally better to use the built-in classes and methods that use this time zone information. I specifically recommend `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`.